# SSR build in Angular showing multiple errors

Tags: angular, npm, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Facing errors when trying to run 'npm run build:ssr'. Another developer added 'node-schedule' + 'puppeteer-core' for a crawling job, with some other packages. Not sure if both issues are related, since it was working perfectly before that.

This is the whole error essentially:

```
./node_modules/clone-deep/utils.js:7:34-41 - Warning: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js:5:8-30 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fast-crc32c' in 'E:\Regaladincompiled\node_modules\hash-stream-validation'

./node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index.cjs.js:364:14-27 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index.cjs.js:541:12-37 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'puppeteer-core' in 'E:\Regaladincompiled\node_modules\puppeteer-extra\dist'

./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js:105:21-42 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in 'E:\Regaladincompiled\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib'

./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/ws/lib/validation.js:86:20-45 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in 'E:\Regaladincompiled\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib'



./node_modules/clone-deep/utils.js:11:0-38 - Error: Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 11

./node_modules/clone-deep/utils.js:12:0-33 - Error: Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 12

./node_modules/clone-deep/utils.js:13:0-28 - Error: Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 13
```

NPM build works, it is the next step that causes the failure. Main.js is not built.

Comment: I would first try to run npm install..

Comment: Any luck with MikeOne's suggestion?

Comment: It does not help. Same issues arise.

Comment: Without a reproduction it will be hard to find a solution

Comment: Seems like it. I am not sure why, and how it is happening. Has literally mentally exhausted me...

Comment: Is it possible to push the code to github? Is it possible to reduce the project to a minimal version that can be shared?